# How to Get An URL of is_single in is_page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am in `is_page` and would like to get a specific url `https://www.jualbotolminum.com/alaska-frozen/`.
I would like to grab a first image on that url and show it. I need a wordpress code version (e.g.function) to make me able to grab an image inside the post.

I used `post ID` but it doesn't work. Using a url paramater is too risk I think.

Here's the [demo](https://www.jualbotolminum.com/beli-tumbler/?action=beli&item=alaska-frozen).

Comment: Since I want a wp version code, I finally find the solution, as in; `<?php
//$linkz = 'https://www.jualbotolminum.com/alaska-frozen/';
if ($query = url_exists($linkz)){
    global $post;
    $postid = url_to_postid( 'alaska-frozen' );
    $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $postid );
    echo $slug;
    }
else{
    echo 'no url like that';
    }
?>`

Comment: This will give you the current url page you're on with wordpress: <?php global $wp; echo add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, home_url( $wp->request ) ); ?>

Comment: @amarinediary, I read the thread in a page of this site, and above (in this comment) has already resolved my problem, thanks. It's a matter of arrange a question - still makes me confused how to express my problem :)

Comment: @amarinediary, your suggestion will return the is_page url not is_single url I targetted.

Comment: Exactly (I didn't understand your question I think ^^)